# Mysql retriving results from a list

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

I am trying to avoid making a huge amount of queries. I am sure that there is a simple solution that I don't know of. What I want to achieve is something like this

```
-------------------------------------------------------
| type        |  06/03  |  08/03  |  15/03  |  04/04  |
-------------------------------------------------------
| single room |    0    |    2    |    3    |    0    |
| double room |    1    |    2    |    5    |    0    |
| suite       |    2    |    2    |    1    |    2    |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

passing some room ids and a list of dates. is there anyway to do this on db side or do I have to go through each room and make a query for each day?

Thank you guys
//R

Comment: SELECT 'single room' type,0 '06/03' etc UNION SELECT 'double room' etc

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

SELECT room_type AS type, dt, count(*) FROM table_name GROUP BY room_type, dt;

Comment: That will bring me all dates. I need some particular dates. I can't use in() too because will mix all results